# Discount fields in different quote tables

Tags: attributes, orders

There are some discount fields like discount_amount/base_discount_amount in sales_flat_quote_item and sales_flat_quote_address. same goes for subtotal_with_discount/base_subtotal_with_discount in sales_flat_quote_address and sales_flat_quote?

why there are same fields in two tables? what do they do?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

A quote can have many items and the discount_amount in sales_flat_quote would be the sum of all discount_amounts of the individual items in sales_flat_quote_item. [1]

A quote can have multiple addresses (standard checkout: billing + shipping, or multi address checkout: billing + X*shipping) and the discount amount in sales_flat_quote would be the sum of all discount amounts in sales_flat_quote_address. [1]

I am not 100% sure why Magento chose to store these in multiple locations - might be performance related or rounding might get applied at various stages which would not allow on-the-fly calculations.

> [1] As a sidenote the above represents the best case scenario,
>   unfortunately there are various bugs around discounts and taxation and
>   the sums might not always equal the individual components, especially
>   on bundled products.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but does that means that; sum of all discount amounts in sales_flat_quote_address = sum of all discount_amounts of the individual items in sales_flat_quote_item = discount_amount in sales_flat_quote?

Comment: also there is not discount_amount in sales_flat_quote, but subtotal_with_discount:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the difference between Subtotal and BaseSubtotal than
Subtotal is the subtotal in the customer's currency and BaseSubtotal is the subtotal in your shop's base currency. 
Example: you have euros and dollars(base currency) installed in your shop.
When customer place an order on your european site with amount 100€, Subtotal will be 100 and BaseSubtotal will be 130 (if 1€ == $1.3).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i did not ask the difference between subtotal and base_subtotal :(